# How to get the last lines of a file except the first 20?

Tags: shell, unix, tail, unix-head

Say I have a file with any number of lines, say, 125. I want to get all the lines except the first n, say, 20. So, I want lines 21–125.

Is there a way to do this with with `tail`/`head`, or some other tool?

Comment: If you want to know what head/tail can do, read the man pages for them. If you did not know that head/tail existed, I could understand why you'd ask the question, but explicitly asking about head/tail deserves a RTFM response.

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604864/print-a-file-skipping-x-lines-in-bash

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try

```
tail -n +21 myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

> `sed -i 1,20d filename`

if you want to delete the first 20 lines !

Answer (score 3):

Awk power can be used too:

```
awk -- 'NR > 20' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm rusty with this but something like:
tail -n +20 filename