# Print a file, skipping the first X lines, in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, printing, skip

I have a very long file which I want to print, skipping the first 1,000,000 lines, for example.

I looked into the cat man page, but I did not see any option to do this. I am looking for a command to do this or a simple Bash program.

Answer (score 1304, accepted):

Use [`tail`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html).  Some examples:

```
$ tail file.log
< Last 10 lines of file.log >
```

To SKIP the first N lines:

```
$ tail -n +<N+1> <filename>
< filename, excluding first N lines. >
```

For instance, to skip the first 10 lines:

```
$ tail -n +11 file.log
< file.log, starting at line 11, after skipping the first 10 lines. >
```

To see the last N lines, omit the "+":

```
$ tail -n <N> <filename>
< last N lines of file. >
```

Comment: Or "tail --lines=+<LinesToSkip> ..." for the readable-commands crowd :-)

Comment: in centos 5.6 `tail -n +1` shows the whole file and `tail -n +2` skips first line. strange. The same for `tail -c +<num>`.

Comment: Nick you may be running up against windows style line endings.

Comment: @JoelClark No, @NickSoft is right. On Ubuntu, it's `tail -n +<start number>`, I just tested it. So `tail -n +1` won't skip anything, but start from the first line instead.

Comment: I can confirm that `tail -n +2` is required to skip the first line on Darwin/Mac OS X as well.

Comment: this must be outdated, but, tail -n+2  OR tail -n +2 works, as with all short commands using getopt, you can run the parameter right next to it's switch, providing that the switch is the last in the group, obviously a command like tail -nv+2 would not work, it would have to be tail -vn+2. if you dont believe me try it yourself.

Comment: On Solaris, you need to use: `/usr/xpg4/bin/tail` (found this in the man page).

Comment: Think I discovered this by accident but both head and tail allow you to omit the `-n` as if it's implied.  You can simply `<command> | tail +2`

Answer (score 181):

Easiest way I found to remove the first ten lines of a file:

```
$ sed 1,10d file.txt
```

In the general case where `X` is the number of initial lines to delete, credit to commenters and editors for this:

```
$ sed 1,Xd file.txt
```

Comment: In the more general case, you'd have to use `sed 1,Xd` where X is the number of initial lines to delete, with X greater than 1.

Comment: This makes more sense if you don't know how long the file is and don't want to tell `tail` to print the last 100000000 lines.

Comment: @springloaded if you need to know the number of lines in the file, ‘wc -l’ will easily give it to you

Answer (score 119):

If you have GNU tail available on your system, you can do the following:

```
tail -n +1000001 huge-file.log
```

It's the `+` character that does what you want.  To quote from the man page:

> If  the  first  character of K (the number of bytes or lines) is a
>   `+', print beginning with the Kth item from the start of each  file.

Thus, as noted in the comment, putting +1000001 starts printing with the first item after the first 1,000,000 lines.

Comment: Works for BSD tail too (OS X)

Comment: @Lloeki Awesome! BSD head doesn't support negative numbers like GNU does, so I assumed tail didn't accept positives (with +) since that's sort of the opposite. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Also, to clarify this answer: `tail -n +2 huge-file.log` would skip first line, and pick up on line 2. So to skip the first line, use +2. @saipraneeth's answer does a good job of exaplaining this.

Answer (score 64):

If you want to skip first two line:

```
tail -n +3 <filename>
```

If you want to skip first x line:

```
tail -n +$((x+1)) <filename>
```

Comment: This is somewhat misleading because someone may interpret `(x+1)` literally. For example, for x=2, they may type either `(2+1)` or even `(3)`, neither of which would work. A better way to write it might be: To skip the first X lines, with Y=X+1, use `tail -n +Y <filename>`

Answer (score 43):

A less verbose version with AWK:

```
awk 'NR > 1e6' myfile.txt
```

But I would recommend using integer numbers.

Comment: useful if you need to skip some lines in the middle of the file, e.g., `awk '!(5 < NR && NR < 10)'`

Comment: This version works in the Cygwin tools that come with Git for Windows, whereas `tail` and `sed` do not. For example `git -c color.status=always status -sb | awk 'NR > 1'` gives a nice minimal status report without any branch information, which is useful when your shell already shows branch info in your prompt. I assign that command to alias `gs` which is really easy to type.

Answer (score 26):

Use the [sed `delete` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Common-Commands.html#Common-Commands) with a [range address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Addresses.html). For example:

```
sed 1,100d file.txt # Print file.txt omitting lines 1-100.
```

Alternatively, if you want to only print a known range, use the print command with the `-n` flag:

```
sed -n 201,300p file.txt # Print lines 201-300 from file.txt
```

This solution should work reliably on all Unix systems, regardless of the presence of GNU utilities.

Comment: Most readily usable answer for both cli and scripting.

Comment: You can use `$` as "address" of eof: `sed -n '201,$p' file.txt`, i.e. *print file from line 201 to the end*.

Answer (score 24):

Use:

```
sed -n '1d;p'
```

This command will delete the first line and print the rest.

Comment: better than tail imo, since we don't have to know the number of lines to be tail-ed. we just remove the 1st line and that's all

Comment: @Tom you don't need to know the number tailed, to skip the first line use `tail +2`

Comment: good point indeed

Answer (score 17):

If you want to see the first 10 lines you can use sed as below:

```
sed -n '1,10 p' myFile.txt
```

Or if you want to see lines from 20 to 30 you can use:

```
sed -n '20,30 p' myFile.txt
```

Answer (score 15):

You can do this using the head and tail commands:

```
head -n <num> | tail -n <lines to print>
```

where num is 1e6 + the number of lines you want to print.

Comment: Not the most efficient answer since you'd need to do a "wc -l" on the file to get a line count, followed by an addition to add the million :-). You can do it with just "tail".

Comment: I'm not sure, my understanding was that 1e6 would be known at the time of calling. Counting backwards isn't the fastest though.

Answer (score 14):

Just to propose a `sed` alternative. :) To skip first one million lines, try `|sed '1,1000000d'`.

Example:

```
$ perl -wle 'print for (1..1_000_005)'|sed '1,1000000d'
1000001
1000002
1000003
1000004
1000005
```

Comment: @Marlon, sorry but that's wrong. That only works for 1d.  If, for example, you use it on 2d, you'll delete only line 2.  It doesn't delete the range of lines.

Comment: @A-B-B sorry, meant to say that this was the easiest solution by far which is why I +1 it not trying to correct the author.

Answer (score 11):

This shell script works fine for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v initial_line=$1 -v end_line=$2 '{
    if (NR >= initial_line && NR <= end_line) 
    print $0
}' $3
```

Used with this sample file (file.txt):

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

The command (it will extract from second to fourth line in the file):

```
edu@debian5:~$./script.sh 2 4 file.txt
```

Output of this command:

```
two
three
four
```

Of course, you can improve it, for example by testing that all argument values are the expected :-)

Comment: ++ for using awk, which is oh so marginally more portable than tail

Answer (score 6):

```
cat < File > | awk '{if(NR > 6) print $0}'
```

Comment: This is a syntax error in bash — in what shell does it work?

Comment: I run this in bash. The < and > are not part of the command, the name of the file should replace "< File >"

Comment: `awk 'NR > 6 {print}'` is sufficient... no need for the if or the $0.

Comment: Actually `awk 'NR>6'` is sufficient as print is the default action block :-) See https://linuxhandbook.com/awk-command-tutorial/ for a really good awk tutorial which explains this well.

Answer (score -2):

I needed to do the same and found this thread.

I tried "tail -n +, but it just printed everything.

The more +lines worked nicely on the prompt, but it turned out it behaved totally different when run in headless mode (cronjob).

I finally wrote this myself:

```
skip=5
FILE="/tmp/filetoprint"
tail -n$((`cat "${FILE}" | wc -l` - skip)) "${FILE}"
```

Comment: Correct link of [Useless Use of Cat Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). The previous is replaced by advert.

Comment: @kub1x I don't think "cat" here is useless, as "cat | wc -l" produces different output than simple "wc -l". The former is suitable for arithmetic operations, the latter is not.

Comment: @Jack I wasn't judging the use of `cat`, but only fixing a link in a comment, that led to a dead page. The original comment must have been deleted. Anyways, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @kub1x You know? After reading the link now I think that the use of "cat" here is wrong :) It should has been something like "wc -l < ${FILE}", saving some overhead time/memory (new process creation, pipelining I/O,.. ). Thanks, I've learned something new