# Extracting n rows of text from a large csv file

Tags: grep, unix

I have a CSV file (foo.csv) with 200,000 rows.  I need to break it into four files (foo1.csv, foo2.csv... etc.) with 50,000 rows each.

I already tried simple ctrl-v/-c using gui text editors, but the my computer slows to a halt.

What unix command(s) could I use to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 6):

you should use `head` and `tail`.

```
head -n 50000 myfile > part1.csv
head -n 100000 myfile | tail -n 50000 > part2.csv 
head -n 150000 myfile | tail -n 50000 > part3.csv
```

etc ...

Else, but with no control on file names, you can use unix command `split`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a terminal handy to try it out, but it should be just [`split -d -l 50000 foo.csv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/split).

Hopefully the naming isn't terribly important because with the `-d` option, the output files will be named `foo.csv00` .. `foo.csv03`.  You can add the `-a 1` option so that the suffixes are 0-3, but there's no simple way to get the suffix to be injected into the middle of the filename.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -n 2000,4000p somefile.txt
```

will print from lines 2000 to 4000 to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

split -l50000 foo.csv

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-28)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this little shell script for [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604864/print-a-file-skipping-x-lines-in-bash/700948#700948) very similar at yours.

This shell script + awk works fine for me:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v initial_line=$1 -v end_line=$2 '{
    if (NR >= initial_line && NR <= end_line) 
    print $0
}' $3
```

Used with this sample file (file.txt):

```
one
two
three
four
five
six
```

The command (it will extract from second to fourth line in the file):

```
edu@debian5:~$./script.sh 2 4 file.txt
```

Output of this command:

```
two
three
four
```

Of course, you can improve it, for example by testing that all argument values are the expected :-)