# How to ignore all lines before a match occurs in bash?

Tags: bash

I would like ignore all lines which occur before a match in bash (also ignoring the matched line. Example of input could be

```
R1-01.sql
R1-02.sql
R1-03.sql
R1-04.sql
R2-01.sql 
R2-02.sql
R2-03.sql
```

and if I match `R2-01.sql` in this already sorted input I would like to get

```
R2-02.sql
R2-03.sql
```

Comment: Can I suggest you also tag this question with `sed`? I could do it myself, but my edit might not be accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Many ways possible. For example: assuming that your input is in list.txt

```
PATTERN="R2-01.sql"
sed "0,/$PATTERN/d" <list.txt
```

because, the `0,/pattern/` works only on GNU sed, (e.g. doesn't works on OS X), here is an *tampered* solution. ;)

```
PATTERN="R2-01.sql"
(echo "dummy-line-to-the-start" ; cat - ) < list.txt | sed "1,/$PATTERN/d"
```

This will add one dummy line to the start, so the real pattern must be on line the 1 or higher, so the `1,/pattern/` will works - deleting everything from the line 1 (dummy one) up to the pattern.

Or you can print lines after the pattern and delete the 1st, like:

```
sed -n '/pattern/,$p' < list.txt | sed '1d'
```

with awk, e.g.:

```
awk '/pattern/,0{if (!/pattern/)print}' < list.txt
```

or, **my favorite** use the next perl command:

```
perl -ne 'print unless 1../pattern/' < list.txt
```

deletes the 1.st line when the pattern is on 1st line...

another solution is reverse-delete-reverse

```
tail -r < list.txt | sed '/pattern/,$d' | tail -r
```

if you have the `tac` command use it instead of `tail -r` The interesant thing is than the `/pattern/,$d' works on the last line but the`1,/pattern/d` doesn't on the first.

Comment: I'm using this, but it doesn't work when the match happens in the first line. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364951/remove-all-lines-before-a-match-with-sed

Comment: @Fabio yes! the correct solution is 0,/pattern/ Thank you, and added a solution what works on non-GNU sed too.

Comment: The reverse-delete-reverse technique saved the day with  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662085/grep-log4j-for-lines-after-certain-timestamp-in-java

Comment: Most of these only work with a hard-coded `pattern` string, not the `$PATTERN` shell variable, which is much more useful.

Answer (score 17):

> How to ignore all lines before a match occurs in bash?

The question headline and your example don't quite match up.

Print all lines *from* "R2-01.sql" in `sed`:

```
sed -n '/R2-01.sql/,$p' input_file.txt
```

Where:

- `-n` suppresses printing the pattern space to stdout
- `/` starts and ends the pattern to match (regular expression)
- `,` separates the start of the range from the end
- `$` addresses the last line in the input
- `p` echoes the pattern space in that range to stdout
- `input_file.txt` is the input file

Print all lines *after* "R2-01.sql" in `sed`:

```
sed '1,/R2-01.sql/d' input_file.txt
```

- `1` addresses the first line of the input
- `,` separates the start of the range from the end
- `/` starts and ends the pattern to match (regular expression)
- `$` addresses the last line in the input
- `d` deletes the pattern space in that range
- `input_file.txt` is the input file
- Everything not deleted is echoed to stdout.

Comment: Will that print the line with the pattern? Seems the OP does not want that.

Comment: @glenn: It depends on which part of the question you read. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This only works with a hard-coded `R2-01.sql` not `$PATTERN`.

Comment: @user5359531: Correct. `$PATTERN` isn't mentioned in the question, but this could be adapted with relative ease.

Comment: Thanks! This was by far the best answer for me. Is it possible to skip everything before the pattern and 3 lines after the pattern while also excluding the line with the pattern?

Answer (score 9):

This is a little hacky, but it's easy to remember for quickly getting the output you need:

```
$ grep -A99999 $match $file
```

Obviously you need to pick a value for `-A` that's large enough to match all contents; if you use a too-small value the output will be silently truncated.

To ensure you get *all* output you can do:

```
$ grep -A$(wc -l $file) $match $file
```

Of course at that point you might be better off with the `sed` solutions, since they don't require two reads of the file.

And if you don't want the matching line itself, you can simply pipe this command into `tail -n+1` to [skip the first line of output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604864/print-a-file-skipping-x-lines-in-bash).

Comment: What if this file contains more than 99999 lines?
I've dealing with files more than 100000 lines, luckily I'm not following your advice.

Comment: The second example will work for any-sized file.  As I said, the first is useful because it's easy to remember.  It's an alternative to the `sed` solution, you don't have to do it this way if you don't want to.

Comment: The latter `grep` command using `wc -l` of the file is the only solution I've seen posted that is truly portable and flexible.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v pattern=R2-01.sql '
  print_it {print} 
  $0 ~ pattern {print_it = 1}
'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do with this,but i think jomo666's answer was better.

```
sed -nr '/R2-01.sql/,${/R2-01/d;p}' <<END
    R1-01.sql
    R1-02.sql
    R1-03.sql
    R1-04.sql
    R2-01.sql
    R2-02.sql
    R2-03.sql
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl is another option:

```
perl -ne 'if ($f){print} elsif (/R2-01\.sql/){$f++}' sql
```

To pass in the regex as an argument, use `-s` to enable a simple argument parser

```
perl -sne 'if ($f){print} elsif (/$r/){$f++}' -- -r=R2-01\\.sql file
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with `grep`, by printing a large enough context following the `$match`. This example will output the first matching line followed by 999,999 lines of "context".

```
grep -A999999 $match $file
```

For added safety (in case the `$match` begins with a hyphen, say) you should use `-e` to force `$match` to be used as an expression.

```
grep -A999999 -e '$match' $file
```