# Get everything in a file after a grep'd string

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep

Yesterday a situation came up where someone needed me to separate out the tail end of a file, specified as being everything after a particular string (for sake of argument, "FOO").  I needed to do this immediately so went with the option that I knew would work and disregarded The Right Way or The Best Way, and went with the following:

```
grep -n FOO FILE.TXT | cut -f1 -d":" | xargs -I{} tail -n +{} FILE.TXT > NEWFILE.TXT
```

The thing that bugged me about this was the use of xargs for a singleton value.  I thought that I could go flex my Google-Fu on this but was interested to see what sort of things people out in SO-land came up with for this situation

Comment: Duplicate of [How to ignore all lines before a match occurs in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5935742/7552)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
sed -n '/re/,$p' file
```

is what occurs to me right off.

Comment: The right tool for the right job. `sed` is what you want. Mod +1.

Comment: (I guess where re means "regular expression") (i.e: sed -n '/search_pattern/,$p' file)

Comment: What if you want to replace `re` with a shell variable? For example, `foo="my pattern"; sed -n '/$foo/,$p' file` does not work because the `'` prevents shell expansion, and `sed -n "/$foo/,$p" file` does not work because the shell tries to expand `$p`, leading to error `sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unexpected `,'`

Answer (score 11):

Did you consider just using grep's '--after-context' argument?

Something like, this should do the trick, with a sufficiently large number to tail out the end of the file:

```
grep --after-context=999999 -n FOO FILE.TXT > NEWFILE.TXT
```

Comment: Don't you need to supply a NUM argument to that?  That was exactly the sort of functionality I was initially thinking of

Comment: Ah, did you add that after initially posting?  I didn't think to do an overly large number.  As an aside 999999 might not have been enough in this case, but your point remains.

Comment: Yes, sorry Geoff, you must have caught me in the middle of making the edit with the example.

Comment: If 999999 may not be sufficient, then `--after-context=$(wc -l < FILE.TXT)` will

Answer (score 1):

Similar to geekosaur's answer above, but this option excludes rather than includes the matched line:

```
sed '1,/regex/d' myfile
```

Found this one [here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/126881-sed-print-all-lines-after-pattern-match.html) after trying the option above.