# How to include variables in the sed command?

Tags: bash, unix, sed

```
grep -F "$name" -A1000 filename | sed -n '1p;19p;24p'
```

Assume `let a=10,b=20,c=30`.In the above grep command can I use `'$ap;$bp;$cp'` instead of `'1p;19p;24p'`?

Another thing, I've given as `-A1000`. Which implies that starting from 1p it considers till 1000 line , right? I need to search throughout file without giving the number.

Comment: use double, not single quotes - `"$ap;$bp;$cp"`

Comment: @ evil otto : I tried in double quotes too. But getting error as invalid path context.

Comment: Jackie, the question would be improved by naming the shell that you are using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to include variables inside quotes, you need to use `"` instead of `'`.

If you want to add alphanumeric suffix to a variable you need to indicate that it's not part of it's name.

```
sed -n "${a}p;${b}p;${c}p"
```

Or:

```
sed -n "$a"'p;'"$b"'p;'"$c"'p'
```

Comment: @ PsulP.R.O. & Banthar : How about -A1000 ? Is it necessary to mention that respective number of lines (1000) ? or is it ok, if i just mention as -A ?

Comment: @JackieJames I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Do you want [all lines after match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968107/get-everything-in-a-file-after-a-grepd-string)?

Comment: @ Banthar : I just want to print the lines in the sed command . How can i make it ?

Comment: @JackieJames If you don't need grep just do: `sed -n '1p;19p;24p' "$name"`

Comment: @ Banthar : Plzz go through thr link 'How to retrieve the specified parameters in a file (Shell Scripting )?' & let me knw which command to use.

Comment: @JackieJames I still don't understand. What are you trying to achieve with `grep -A1000` and why isn't it good?

Comment: @ Banthar : Tell me, wat does this command perform 
sed -n '1p;19p;24p' "$name" ?

Comment: @ Banthar : does this command sed -n '1p;19p;24p' "$name" require file name in it ?