# How can I delete all lines before a specific string from a number of files

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have n files, like:

file1:

```
1aaa
2eee

Test        XXX
Hanna
Lars
```

file2:

```
1fff
2ddd
3zzz

Test        XXX
Mike
Charly
```

I want to remove all rows before "Test   XXX" from all n files.
The number of rows to delete varies between files.

My idea:

```
for file in 1 :n
do
pos=grep -n "Test XXX" file$file
sed -i "1:$pos-1 d" file$file >new$file
done
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: seems a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935742/how-to-ignore-all-lines-before-a-match-occurs-in-bash

Answer (score 29):

This should work for you:

```
sed -i '1,/Test XXX/d' file1
sed -i '1,/Test XXX/d' file2
```

or simply

```
sed -i '1,/Test XXX/d' file*
```

Comment: Be careful with this you will lose the original file.

Comment: That is exactly the purpose of the -i (inline) option.

Comment: Just use `-i.bak` if you want to create a backup file at the same time.

Comment: sed '1,/Test XXX/d' < file > newfile

Comment: This seems to fail if the matched line is the first line.

Comment: This seems to be answering a different question; the question was how to delete lines BEFORE a specific line, not including.

Comment: how can i remove all rows after some string?

Comment: This, unfortunately, deletes the Test XXX line as well... : /

Comment: Be careful if you use this in shell script , if you use variable for sed argument, replace single quote with double qoute

Comment: pro to @Jewenile, it eats first match line. Alec Jacobson's answer solves this problem.

Answer (score 10):

This will work for your examples and even if the matched pattern is on the very first line:

```
sed -n -E -e '/Text XXX/,$ p' input.txt | sed '1 d'
```

For example if you input is simply

```
Test        XXX
Mike
Charly
```

This will give you

```
Mike
Charly
```

If you want to keep the first match `Test        XXX` then just use:

```
sed -n -E -e '/Text XXX/,$ p' input.txt
```

Comment: I find a url talking undocument -E (however it seems a ded link; thanks to Google, it has web-storage version). It's eqivalent with -r, which for compatible with BSD ( see the code segment in that dead link page:
        `/* Undocumented, for compatibility with BSD sed.  */
        case 'E':
        case 'r':
          if (extended_regexp_flags)
            usage(4);
          extended_regexp_flags = REG_EXTENDED;
          break;
           .  .  .`

Comment: That link is sometimes ok, so I'll post its url here: http://blog.dmitryleskov.com/small-hacks/mysterious-gnu-sed-option-e/

Comment: From the manual (`man sed`):  `-E, -r, --regexp-extended` ; 

             `use  extended regular expressions in the script (for portability
              use POSIX -E).`  Also https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Extended-regexps.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `bash` ( eg for 1 file)

```
t=0
while read -r line
do
    [[ $line =~ Test.*XXX ]] && t="1"
    case "$t" in
     1) echo "$line";;
    esac
done < file > tempo && mv tempo file
```

Use a `for` loop as necessary to go through all the files

Answer (score 1):

```
cat <<-EOF > file1.txt
1aaa
2eee

Test        XXX
Hanna
Lars
EOF

cat file1.txt | sed -e '/Test *XXX/p' -e '0,/Test *XXX/d'
```

Output:

```
Test        XXX
Hanna
Lars
```

Explanation:

- `-e '/Test *XXX/p'` duplicates the line matching `/Test *XXX/`
- `-e '0,/Test *XXX/d'` deletes from line 0 to the first line matching `/Test *XXX/`

By duplicating the line, then removing the first one, we effectively retain the matched line, successfully deleting all lines BEFORE `Test    XXX`

Note: this will not work as expected if there are multiple `Test    XXX` lines.