# Delete all lines before first occurrence of specific string in file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Basically I have a file like:

```
junk
morejunk
somestring
bats
car
somestring
bats
car
somestring
bats
car
```

and I want to remove all of the `junk` before the first occurrence of `somestring` so the file looks like

```
somestring
bats
car
somestring
bats
car
somestring
bats
car
```

I followed the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416921/how-can-i-delete-all-lines-before-a-specific-string-from-a-number-of-files) to use `sed -i '0,/somestring/,d' file.txt` but it deletes the line with the first occurrence of `somestring`, when I want to keep that line as the first line.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With `sed` you could use:

```
sed -i '/somestring/,$!d' file
```

Explanation of replace expressions:

> <sub>`,` matches lines starting from where the first
>   address matches, and continues until the second match
>   (inclusively).</sub>
>
> <sub>`$` matches the last line of the last file of input,
>   or the last line of each file when the -i or -s options are
>   specified.</sub>
>
> <sub>`!` If the character follows an address range, then only lines
>   which do not match the address range will be selected.</sub>
>
> <sub>`d` Delete the pattern space; immediately start next cycle.</sub>

Result:

```
$ sed -i '/somestring/,$!d' file
somestring
bats
car
somestring
bats
car
somestring
bats
car
```

Comment: Thank you.  (years later...)  This helped me a lot.

Comment: For those who want to after a match it would be something like this:
  
`sed '/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/q;$d'`

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way you can do it using awk:

```
awk '/somestring/ { f = 1 } f' file
```

When the pattern matches, set `f` to true. When `f` becomes true, print each line.

Another option, slightly more cryptic:

```
awk 'f += /somestring/' file
```

`f` is increased by either `1` when the pattern matches or `0` when it doesn't. Once a line has matched the pattern, the expression becomes true, so each line is printed.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -n '/somestring/,$p' infile
somestring
bats
car
somestring
bats
car
somestring
bats
car
```

The command suppresses printing with `-n`, and then for the address range `/somestring/,$`, i.e., from `somestring` to the last line, executes the `p` command to print the line.

Comment: I offered a [different solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35965998/1301972) based on code the OP already had at hand, but yours is a better sed-only solution. Your solution also works with both GNU and BSD seds, so +1 for that.

Comment: @CodeGnome Appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

another idiomatic `awk` solution (and fewest keystrokes) is

```
$ awk '/somestring/,0' file   

somestring
bats
car
somestring
bats
car
somestring
bats
car
```

Answer (score 0):

### Concatenate with Echo and GNU Sed

You had most of the solution with GNU sed, which allows you to use both line numbers and regular expressions in range patterns. All you really need to do to get the behavior you want is to prepend the string you're using as your end-pattern to the resulting output.

For example:

```
$ str='somestring'; echo -e "${str}\n$(sed "0,/${str}/d" /tmp/corpus)"
somestring
bats
car
somestring
bats
car
somestring
bats
car
```

Basically, you assign the pattern to *str*, which you then reuse in both the echo statement and the sed expression. If you run into quoting problems related to variable interpolation, just replace the *str* variable with fixed strings in both your echo and sed commands. However, works as-is with the posted corpus.