# How can I delete all lines after a specific string from a number of files

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have n files, like:

file1:

```
Hannah
Lars

Test 123
1aaa
2eee
```

file2:

```
Mike
Charly
Stephanie
Earl

Test 123
3ccc
4ddd
5eee
```

I want to remove all rows after "Test   123" from all n files.
The number of rows to delete varies between files.

There's a very similar question [How can I delete all lines before a specific string from a number of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416921/how-can-i-delete-all-lines-before-a-specific-string-from-a-number-of-files) in which `sed -i.bak '1,/Test 123/d' file*` works perfectly, but how can I do it for all lines after a specific string?

Thanks!

Comment: See: [How to remove all lines after a line containing some string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65513225/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

Despite the comments and closed question, nothing in other threads worked. Figured out a solution:

```bash
for FILENAME in * ; do sed -i.bak '/Test 123/q' $FILENAME ; done
```

Comment: I suggest to use only `sed -i.bak '/Test 123/q' *`.

Comment: Or even `xargs`! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939038/how-do-you-run-a-command-eg-chmod-for-each-line-of-a-file