# remove n lines from STDOUT on bash

Tags: bash, sed, tail, unix-head

Do you have any bash solution to remove N lines from stdout?

like a 'head' command, print all lines, only except last N

Simple solition on bash:

> find ./test_dir/ | sed '$d' | sed '$d' | sed '$d' | ...

but i need to copy sed command N times

Any better solution?
except awk, python etc...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print a file skipping X lines in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604864/print-a-file-skipping-x-lines-in-bash)

Comment: That link is for skipping the first X lines, not the last X lines.

Answer (score 7):

Use `head` with a negative number. In my example it will print all lines but last 3:

```
head -n -3 infile
```

Comment: `$head -n -3 somefile.ext` throws error `head: illegal line count -- -3` on OSX / BSD General Commands Manual

Answer (score 2):

if head -n -3 filename doesn't work on your system (like mine), you could also try the following approach (and maybe alias it or create a function in your .bashrc)

```
head -`echo "$(wc -l filename)" | awk '{ print $1 - 3; }'` filename
```

Where *filename* and *3* above are your file and number of lines respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The `tail` command can skip from the end of a file on Mac OS / BSD. `tail` accepts `+/-` prefix, which facilitates expression below, which will show 3 lines from the start

```
tail -n +3 filename.ext
```

Or, to skip lines from the end of file, use `-` prefixed, instead.

```sh
tail -n -3 filenme.ext
```

Typically, the default for `tail` is the `-` prefix, thus counting from the end of the file. See a similar answer to a different question here:  [Print a file skipping first X lines in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604864/print-a-file-skipping-first-x-lines-in-bash)