# How to replace two lines with a blank line using SED command?

Tags: linux

I want to replace the first two lines with a blank line as below.

**Input:**

```
sample
sample
123
234
235
456
```

**Output:**

```
<> blank line
123
234
235
456
```

Comment: got the answer here [skipping lines in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604864/print-a-file-skipping-the-first-x-lines-in-bash) tl;dr: sed 1,2d file.txt

Comment: this is rmoving first two lines but blank line should be there in output file...

Answer (score 1):

Delete the first line, remove all the content from the second line but don't delete it completely:

```bash
$ sed -e '1d' -e '2s/.*//' input.txt

123
234
235
456
```

Or **i**nsert a blank line before the first, and delete the first two lines:

```bash
$ sed -e '1i\
' -e '1,2d' input.txt

123
234
235
456
```

Or use `tail` instead of `sed` to print all lines starting with the third, and an `echo` first to get a blank line:

```bash
(echo ""; tail +3 input.txt)
```

Or if you're trying to modify a file in place, use `ed` instead:

```bash
ed -s input.txt <<EOF
1,2c

.
w
EOF
```

(The `c` command **c**hanges the given range of lines to new content)

Comment: It's worked for me as expected thank you .... $ sed -e '1i\ ' -e '1,2d' input.txt